# Is this achievable in OS X TextView? (wrap with indent)

Tags: macos, nstextview

See screenshot from Sublime Text 2

[image]

The second line is wrapped with indent. Can I do this with standard TextView in OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Text System User Interface Layer Programming Guide: Setting Text Margins](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/SetTextMargins.html), you would set a mutable paragraph style object's `firstLineHeadIndent` and `headIndent` to do that. So:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* style = [NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle];
style.headIndent = style.firstLineHeadIndent = 40;
[textView.textStorage addAttribute:style value:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName range:NSMakeRange(0, textView.textStorage.length)];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need visually indent wrapped lines (aka IDE editor) without modifying text storage attributes, then subclassing of `NSATSTypesetter` is needed. See my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47609984/1418981).

Comment: Do you still know how you did it with `NSATSTypesetter`? I currently need this.

Comment: @Fabian Strange that my SO question was deleted by Community. Here is a copy Gist: https://gist.github.com/vgorloff/89587daac4c8c5ea1b237d0f269f75de

Comment: Does not seem to work for me, sadly. I commented out the part with TextString though, I didn't know how its supposed to be used. Thank you anyway for the trouble!